# Auto save files persist even when auto-save-file-name-transforms is changed

Tags: auto-save

I have the following in my configs,

```lisp
(use-package files
  :custom
    (auto-save-file-name-transforms `((".*" ,786:BACKUP-DIR t)))
    (backup-directory-alist `(("." . ,786:BACKUP-DIR)))
    (backup-by-copying t "don't delink hardlinks")
    (version-control t "use version numbers on backups")
    (delete-old-versions t "automatically delete excess backups")
    (kept-new-versions 20 "how many newest and old versions to keep")
    (kept-old-versions 5))
```

This changes the value of `auto-save-file-name-transforms` to,

```
((".*" "/Users/user/.config/emacs/.cache/backup/" t))
```

If I understand, this should now save the auto save or the files prefixed `.#` in `/Users/user/.config/emacs/.cache/backup/` and that does happen but they also get saved in the current working directory.

I did not notice this before, is that a recent change or a bug maybe?

I am on MacOS Sonoma `14.0 (23A344)` and `M-x emacs-version` gives,

```
GNU Emacs 29.1 (build 1, aarch64-apple-darwin21.6.0, NS appkit-2113.60 Version 12.6.6 (Build 21G646)) of 2023-08-16
```

Comment: Are you confusing backup files and autosave files? They are 2 different concepts. Also, can you please share your A. platform , B. Emacs version ? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think so. The backup files are being put in the right directory. It is the auto-save files that aren't. I added more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think your regex is wrong, you are missing `*`

Could you try

```
(auto-save-file-name-transforms `((".*" ,786:BACKUP-DIR t)))
(backup-directory-alist `((".*" . ,786:BACKUP-DIR)))
```

This part `".*"` is regex, and if it's wrong, it can likely ignore the setting.